# Comparing two events

Tags: probability, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real random variables, $X$ a real random variable and $\varepsilon > 0$

Let $A_n$ be the event $ \{ | X_n - X | \geq \varepsilon \} $ and $B_n$ the event $ \{ \sup_{k \geq n} | X_k - X | \geq \varepsilon \} $

I was wondering if we can compare $B_n$ and $ \lim \sup A_n $

Thank you for your answer,

Answer (score 0):

$$\bigcup_{m\geq n}\{|X_m-X|\geq \varepsilon \}\subset B_n$$
therefore $\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n\subset B_n.$

Comment: You mean $ \varepsilon $ instead of $ \infty $ right ?

Comment: @W.314: yes sorry

Comment: No it is ok thank you for your answer. Then what about $\cap B_n$ and $\lim \sup A_n$

Comment: Obviousy $\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n\subset \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$.

Comment: and what about the other inclusion ?

Comment: It won't hold a priori. @W.314